# this is undefined in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I have a class.

```
export class DatabaseHelper {

    public browserID : number;
    private ConfigID = 17;
}
```

Now, in the same class I am trying to access the `ConfigID`

```
SetBrowserID() {
        browser.getCapabilities().then(function (cap) {

            this.browserID = new commFnctions.appdata().getBrowserIDFromBrowserName(cap.get('browserName'));
        });
    }
```

this is giving me error as:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'browserID' of undefined
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [forEach Typescript TS2339 "does not exist on type 'void'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263725/foreach-typescript-ts2339-does-not-exist-on-type-void)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really the basic of a Typescript... use *arrow function*:

```
SetBrowserID() {
    browser.getCapabilities()
       //.then(function (cap) {
       .then((cap) => {

        this.browserID = new commFnctions
                .appdata()
                .getBrowserIDFromBrowserName(cap.get('browserName'));
    });
}
```

Read more about it

#### [Arrow Function](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html) by Basarat

Comment: If that helped anyhow.. great ;) Enjoy Typescript