# forEach Typescript TS2339 "does not exist on type 'void'"

Tags: typescript

Trying to find the intersection of two arrays, why am I getting `TS2339:Property 'collection' does not exist on type 'void'`?

All arrays are declared in the same class.

```
this.locations.forEach(function(location) {
    this.collection.locations.forEach(function(id) {
        if(location._id === id) {
            this.display.push(location);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Because you're not using arrow functions: `this.locations.forEach(location => { ... });`. Same for the other one, of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using a `function` takes the `this` from the caller (something in `forEach` in your case); using `=>` takes the `this` from the outer scope. Thus use:

```
this.locations.forEach(location => {
    this.collection.locations.forEach(id => {
        if(location._id === id) {
            this.display.push(location);
        }
    });
});
```

I recommend the following readings:

- [A Refresher on `this`](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/features/refresher_on_this.html)
- [Arrow Functions](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/features/arrow_functions.html)